# My JQuery image slideshow does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learning JQuery and I wanted to learn how to code a simple image slideshow, so I watch a tutorial on youtube and copied the code. When I tested it, it does nothing. I have tried changing the jquery link to the latest one but still no luck.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="jqslideshow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="nature.jpg" id="slideshow" width="500" height="300">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><a href="javascript:changeImage(-1)">Previous</a></td>
      <td align="right"><a href="javascript:changeImage(1)">Next</a></td>
      <td id="play_stop" align="right"><a href="javascript:play()" >Play</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is `jqslideshow.js`

```
var Image = new Array("nature.jpg","treehouse.jpg","drstrange.jpg");
var ImageNumber = 0;
var ImageLength = Image.length - 1;
var Interval;
function changeImage(num){
  ImageNumber = ImageNumber + num;
  if(ImageNumber > ImageLength){
    ImageNumber = 0;
  }else if(ImageNumber < 0){
    ImageNumber = ImageLength;
  }
  $("document").ready(function(){
    $('#slideshows').fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $(this).attr('src', Image[ImageNumber]);
    }).fadeIn('slow');  
  });
}

function play(){
  Interval = setInterval(changeImage(1), 200);
  document.getElementById("play_stop").innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:stop()'>Stop</a>";
}

function stop(){
  document.getElementById("play_stop").innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:play()'>Play</a>";
  clearInterval(Interval);
}
```

Comment: is the code underneath the `/////` actually in a separate file?

Comment: try to delete quotes around document: $(document).ready(...

Comment: at first look, `$("document").ready` should be `$(document).ready`

Comment: BTW open browser console and look for errow messages. If you use chrome press Ctrl + Shift + J to open console or install Firebug extension if you use firefox

Comment: Yes it's a seperate file, sorry if it confused you.

Comment: @dKab I don't see any error in the console, in fact whenever I click one of the options, it showed in the bottom left that it's clicked but it doesn't seem to respond.

Comment: Can you pls include your [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) ??

Comment: `Image` is a name of JS class. Using it will make your code unstable (even if it works with one browser it will not work with another one). Use lowercase variable names to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, that you change

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $('#slideshows').fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $(this).attr('src', Image[ImageNumber]);
    }).fadeIn('slow');  
  });
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slideshow').fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $(this).attr('src', Image[ImageNumber]);
    }).fadeIn('slow');  
  });
```

So remove the quotes, and more importantly, change the id to `slideshow`, for you named the image tag that way.

Also make sure, that the images are in the same directory, as the html file or create relative paths.

If this still won't work, use your console in the browser.